# Do any languages support range comparisons using "1 < i < 10" syntax?

Tags: comparison, compare, equality

In comparison, instead of using `1 < i && i < 10` can we use `1 < i < 10`? As you can see the latter saves space and the readability is increased.

Is this possible in any programming language?

**EDIT:**

In Javascript, `1 < i < 10` will always return true regardless of what i equals. For example,
`1 < 44 < 10` returns true.

Comment: Python and Perl support it. But this is typically not the primary reason for choosing one language over another.

Comment: I'm not using this as a reason to choose one language over the other. Seems like a silly reason to do so. I'm more or less wanting to know if I can simplify my code at all.

Comment: Then you have to tell us what language you are using.

Comment: Some people would argue that compacting logic i not always the best way to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not support it. For example, `-3 < -2 < -1` results in `false`. For positive values, it sometimes "looks" like it is working, but there is implicit type conversion going on.  For example, `3 < 4 < 5` gives `true`, but this value really comes from `(3<4)<5`, which is equal to `true < 5`, which is equal to `1 < 5 === true`.

Comment: Other than writing a function and using the norm, is there a way around this? Still interested in other languages as well, especially PHP and Java.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around using two separate comparisons as you have indicated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is supported [in Python](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily; for example, x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Example:

```
1 < 2 < 3    # true (correct)  - equivalent to 1 < 2 and 2 < 3
1 < 4 < 3    # false (correct) - equivalent to 1 < 4 and 4 < 3
(1 < 4) < 3  # true ("incorrect")

3 > 2 > 1    # true (correct)  - equivalent to 3 < 2 and 2 < 1
3 > 4 > 1    # false (correct) - equivalent to 3 > 4 and 4 > 1
3 > (4 > 1)  # true ("incorrect")
```

This feature is merely an artifact of a *particular* programming language (e.g Python) and most languages (e.g. JavaScript) *only* treat/parse comparison operators (i.e. `<`) as a *leftward-associative binary operators*.

As such, where such syntax is even well-typed, `a < b < c` is generally *not* a "range" comparisons, but with few exceptions (e.g. Python), is parsed as `(a < b) < c`.